# Is the Period Symbol (.) Ever Used as an Operator

Tags: notation

Are there any cases in which `x.y` (where `x` and `y` are both integers) would produce some kind of result or be interpreted as anything other than a decimal number?

This question relates to [this MathML question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191708/mathml-mo-tag-wrapping-a-decimal-point/34203517#34203517) asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: In some countries,  $x.y$ is used to denote the product of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Now that you mention it, I'm pretty sure I used to use it as shorthand [way] back in high school.  Thank you for reminding me about that.

Comment: Perhaps things are changing with the homogenization of the world, but at one time the period was often used for product in England, Scotland, and Wales.

Comment: Let me ask you this, would it be used exclusively with variables (ie `x.y`) or would it ever be used with actual numbers (ie `1.2`).  The reason I ask is that I'm wondering if I could write a script to remove the MathML bug as outlined in the link.  In MathML, variables have a different tag (`<mi>`) than numbers (`<mn>`).  That would mean I could target `<mo>` tags containing a `.` and surrounded by two `<mn>` tags for replacement.

Comment: I don't know. The decimal point was a centered dot, but that still leaves potential for confusion.

Comment: Build versions and IP Addresses come to mind where there can be multiple dots used though that is outside of Math in a sense. $127.0.0.1$ would be an IP Address that may otherwise be confusing and some may be written in Hexadecimal at times.